# Why does the spontaneous emission rate scale with energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

Good afternoon,

the standard description of spontaneous emission in quantum optics is - to my knowledge - via coupling of an excited atom to vacuum modes of the em-field, which are still occupied at $T \to 0$ due to zero-point fluctuation. These vacuum modes then cause "stimulated emission" at the corresponding wavelength. Virtual photons thus induce spontaneous emission.
To my understanding, all modes of the em-field should be equally occupied at $T \to 0$. Which seems to suggest that the all energy levels should have the same decay rate.

However, it is of course a well-known fact that the natural emission rate of a two-level system depends on its transition energy. Using Wigner-Weisskopf theory, for example, we can derive $$\Gamma \propto \omega^3.$$

I can understand the mathematical derivation, but I cannot connect the two concepts. Do you guys know an intuitive explanation that includes both concepts? Preferably coming from a quantum field perspective.

Thank you and best regards,

Till